# Can you explain how you calculate baseline and Custom BLEU scores?

Tags: microsoft-translator

I understand that tokenization criteria are critical to the BLEU scores that one gets, but what I don’t understand is why I am getting inconsistent differences when I compare baseline BLEU scores or Custom BLEU scores. Let me explain.

For instance, I recently trained an English-Danish Custom model with a training set of around 300k segments and a test set or around 2k segments. Once finished, I got a baseline bleu of 34,63 and a Custom bleu of 48,3. Just to double-check these scores, I recalculated the bleu scores of the Model “System Test Results” downloaded from the Custom Translator portal with the Moses tokenizer.perl and the mult-bleu.perl and with the baseline model I get a bleu score of 34,16, but with the Custom model I get 41,57.

How do you explain that with the baseline model I get a very similar score to the one I get from Microsoft, but with the Custom model I get a score about seven points lower than the one I get from Microsoft. The Danish case is just an example, but this is the behavior I observed with several other languages.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please contact us on the custommt support alias?  I'd like to see your wordbroken test data and determine why there is such a drastic difference.